# How can we add scroll event to sap.m.semantic.FullscreenPage?

Tags: sapui5

I used the following code to add a scroll event to `sap.m.semantic.FullscreenPage` instance but was not successful.

```
var oPage = this.byId("__fullscreen_page_worklist");
oPage.attachBrowserEvent("window.onscroll", function(oEvent) {
    console.log(oEvent);
});
```

While for `sap.m.page` it works. What must be change?

Comment: Is the ID different? UI5 generates it's own ID's when you don't provide one.

Comment: No. It can find the page.